# Best way to update item perms for multiple users with SP REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, rest

Using SharePoint REST API I can add and remove user permissions for a list item. If I need to add permissions for multiple users to a specific item, is there a way to do this other than looping the post for each one or creating a SP group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if is it the best way, but I have created a Flow, with HTTP Trigger and input parameters: 
siteurl, listName, itemId, and an array of user-permisison objects like:

```
{
  "siteUrl": "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/site",
  "listName": "Documents",
  "itemId": "1",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "userId": 8,
      "roleDefinitionId": "@{variables('RoleEdit')}"
    },
      "userId": 10,
      "roleDefinitionId": "@{variables('RoleEdit')}"
    },
    {
      "userId": 11,
      "roleDefinitionId": "@{variables('RoleFull')}"
    }
  ]
}
```

It is easy to reuse in any list with one REST call,
but inside the flow I am looping trough the users and set the permissions one by one, because there is no other way with SharePoint REST API.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no way other than looping the post for each one or creating a SharePoint group.

By REST API, it only can add permission for one user by one REST API post.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this with a workflow that is started on editing items. I modify a field specifically for this purpose per REST to trigger the workflow and let it set the permissions. Might not fit your scenario with a dynamic list of users, but perhaps the idea can help nevertheless.